# Relational Database - Better option in designing fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to choose between two options for my table designs.

In the two tables "CLASS" and "SECTION" listed below, for each "YEAR-CLIENT_ID-CLS_SEQ" combination in the "CLASS" table, there would be 1 or more entries in the "SECTION" table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Info:**
Both the tables CLASS and SECTION are master data, that is, setup done manually and no programmatic updates are done.
There are other child transaction tables where CLS_SEQ and SEC_SEQ are used; and all the transaction tables also have columns YEAR and CLENT_ID.

**Query:**
In terms of table design, which option is better for CLS_SEQ and SEC_SEQ?

Since they are master data setup, my preference is Option 1 since it provides clarity on the data and makes it easy to maintain, year after year. Also in Option 1, the data in the further transaction tables can also be retrieved by passing YEAR and CLIENT_ID (which are always available in the application) along with CLS_SEQ and/or SEC_SEQ.

My question is, would it have any drastic impact on the performance while retrieving data & in joins by using Option 1? Since whenever I need to pull ‘some data’ from CLASS or SECTION tables using a join from any of the child/transaction table, I always need to use YEAR and CLIENT_ID fields too.

Also please note that only the last 4 years records would be maintained in all master and transaction tables and the rest would be archived.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for option 1.

Looking at your data set( and the fact that you will purge after 4 years), it does not look like its going to have the number of records which will really impact performance. Besides, if performance is an issue, there are other options ( query tuning, defining indexes etc) which can be done before worrying about how to structure data.

Technically, in option 2, you are using section sequence as a unique id. If you use that to fetch other tables, it will definitely make it single primary key and hence slightly faster.

On the other hand, you will increase application complexity,as you might need to maintain an additional key in your memory.

In my opinion, its not worth the trouble. DB's are fast enough to handle one join. Its not worth complicating your code.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your time on this. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the "need to maintain an additional key in your memory". I have actually implemented Option-2 already but don't feel comfortable with that.  In both CLASS and SECTION tables I expect the number of records to run in 1000s (at the max 10000s) but the other transaction tables may have million records. Still I too think Option-1 would be best since these tables are manually maintained, it could be a nightmare with Option-2.

Comment: My assumption is that while using other tables which you have not shared, you will be using the section sequence key. Since this is derived key, You would need to save it somewhere, or fetch it from the master table every time you need to access the other tables, where as with option 1, you can always access other tables if you have the inputs.

Comment: Thanks again. The other child tables are like Exam, Mark etc, where either CLS_SEQ (OR) SEC_SEQ will be the foreign key. All the necessary input fields, Year, Client_id, Cls_seq / Sec_seq will always be available as input to read/join the tables.